# Unity HumanTrait.GetMuscleDefaultMax() get by name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a bone's muscle max, but I can't seem to access it. I know which bone I want, but I don't know how to access it other than to loop through an array of all the bones.

Is there a way to just get the muscle information? This doesn't work:

```
selected = Selection.activeGameObject.transform.root.gameObject;

Animator anim = selected.GetComponent<Animator>();

float indexMax = HumanTrait.GetMuscleDefaultMax(HumanBodyBones.LeftIndexProximal);
```

This gives me a transform of the object but that isn't what I am looking for:

```
Transform index1 = anim.GetBoneTransform(HumanBodyBones.LeftIndexProximal);
```

How can I get `HumanTrait.GetMuscleDefaultMax` without looping through all the bones?

Answer (score 0):

This method seems to do the trick (The `BoneInfo` class needs to be created with public properties):

```
BoneInfo GetBoneInfo(HumanBodyBones id) {

    int boneid = (int)id.GetHashCode();
    BoneInfo info = new BoneInfo();

    info.muscleMax = HumanTrait.GetMuscleDefaultMax(boneid);
    info.muscleMin = HumanTrait.GetMuscleDefaultMin(boneid);
    info.transform = anim.GetBoneTransform(id);

    return info;
}
```